# Google maps with overlays into pdf

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, pdf, pdf-generation

My current project is using google maps with overlays. I need to be able to convert this maps into a pdf. The only way I can currently think of this working is to make an image of the maps after the overlays have been applied. I know this isnt the best type of question because it not a code q and a.

Is there a better way of getting the map/overlay into a pdf?

If this is the best way how should I go about this (create the image)?

I am not asking for the code to be written, just some pointer(s) on the best way or reaching the end goal.

Also I am using javascript/jquery to handle gmaps and MVC3 on backend

Comment: Have you looked into static maps from Google? You might be able to get what you need but without relying on Javascript. It's not as flexible, but allows you to create a static image you can then simply either Save as PDF using a third party library (.net) or, simply as an image on it's own ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need permission from Google to do that. See:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_screenshots

Other than that, javascript has no access to the file system to save a pdf, so you'd need to send an AJAX call to the server with the relevant map information and create the pdf server side.